# How to get value from nested, multidimensional array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I created a map with Google Maps with info windows.
I would like to print out the info window content dynamically.
So that I created an array of values as a nested array but I cannot get the value in this nested/multidimensional array.
So that my goal is to run **first,second,third,fourth,fifth** in **content** part of the snippet.

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
            var map;
            var elevator;
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 1,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

             let addresses = [
                 ['Norway','first'],
                 ['Africa','second'],
                 ['Asia','thrid'],
                 ['North America','fourth'],
                 ['South America','fifth']
            ];



            for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
                //usleep(1000000);
                $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x][0]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
                    var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: addresses[x][0]
                    });

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: 'addresses'
                    });

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        alert("Marker clicked");
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });


                });
            }

        });
```

When I do like

```
content: addresses[x][1]
```

It gives me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/P2QhE/5961/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
addresses.forEach(address => console.log(address[1]))
```

Or a much more verbose version:

```
addresses[0][1]
addresses[1][1]
addresses[2][1]
addresses[3][1]
addresses[4][1]
```

Comment: I am trying like content: addresses[x][1] to make it dynamic but it gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined error

Comment: Yes, because you do an async request in line 23, and your for loop finishes before the request is fulfilled. You should change `var` to `let` in line 21

Comment: If you would like to have deeper understanding of closures check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures